# React with Axios can't map array to list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to map all the names in this object but I can't figure out how to access the array. How can i map an object that has multiple array values?  Sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ApiTest = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

      setData(result.data);
      console.log(typeof result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <a>{item.name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ApiTest;
```

Comment: Alex your answer worked!  Why is your answer deleted?

Comment: Alex's Original answer : // Set the initial state as an empty array where you can store your response:
// instead of this:
// const [data, setData] = useState({ name: [] }); do this: const [data, setData] = useState([]); that should work

Comment: I thought I was interacting with the actual response object and not where I stored the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will correct the issue
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

Comment: You don't have to use ``.then(...)`` after your axios call when you are usig async / await syntax. Just changing your initial state to an empty array fixes the problem ;)